# Multiple key binding on (keydown) event in angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

I have used (keydown) event in angular 6 to bind key inputs

So on enter of 'Tab' and 'Enter' key i have to do my functionality
and added a event.prevent default

But when Shift + Tab is entered it is also preventing the event

**.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Result1 (keydown)="onKeydownMain($event)"  >
```

I dont want (keydown.shift.tab) event seperate..

**.ts**

```
public onKeydownMain(event): void {
    if (event.key === "Enter" || event.key === "Tab") {
                event.preventDefault();
                   // My Functionality goes here
    }
}
```

> But the problem is when Shift + Tab is pressed , event is fired and functionality goes on, which i don't want.

How can i go this

I just want Shift + Tab to perform its default functionality on this input.

Comment: You'll have to be explicit and tell it to check if Shift is pressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `shift` in the `if` condition like this:

```
public onKeydownMain(event): void {
       if (!event.shiftKey && (event.key === "Enter" || event.key === "Tab")){
                event.preventDefault();
                   // My Functionality goes here
        }
    }
```

You can refer to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_keyboardevent.asp for `KeyboardEvent`

Comment: Thanks,Sometimes finding simple things we think a lot..That works thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding the shift keyevent value 16 in your code. 
event.which is used to display the keyevent value.

```
alert(event.which);
event.preventDefault();
if (event.keyCode!=16 && (event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 9 )) {
    alert("Pressed enter");
}
```

Comment: When providing an answer please explain why this is the best approach. Answers which just tell the OP to perform some action will not teach them anything. Use links to online documentation to support your claims (e.g. MDN).

Comment: You only get a keyCode with the event. So shiftKey, altKey and ctrlKey is the way to find if a control key was pressed.