# Create Hot keys in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

Please advise how to create short cut keys in Angular web application (Ex: Shift + A or Shift +K).

My current implementation doesn't work:

```
    onKeydown1($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if ($event.shiftKey && $event.key == "A") {
      console.log("action 1");
    }
  }
```

```html
<div (window:keydown)="onKeydown1($event)">
</div>
```

Comment: I copied your code to stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cmuykc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and it works fine. If i press `shift+A` it does print `action1` to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hotkey-bind-kgkswx

If you will use this function in lots of sections, you can create a directive for it.

The code in the directive should be something like:

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if ((e.key === 'A' && e.shiftKey === true)) {
        // Do nothing
        console.log("action 1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an article](https://netbasal.com/diy-keyboard-shortcuts-in-your-angular-application-4704734547a2) I found on google really quickly.

Here's also another [stack overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52665812/multiple-key-binding-on-keydown-event-in-angular-6)

But for actions like that where we're listening for a specific combination of keys (i.e. shift + a), we can listen for (keydown.shift.a)="foo($event)). Your implementation doesn't work since it's listening for shift + CAPITAL A and not shift + lowercase a.